# Normalizing a joint PDF $f(x,y)$ and finding the marginal PDF's $f_X(x) $ and $f_Y(y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

I have the following joint PDF:

$$f_{UV}(u,v):= C \cdot \unicode[STIXGeneral]{x1D7D9}_{\{ (u,v): 0\le u \le 1, u \le v \le u+1 \}}(u,v)$$

(In case the subscript of the indicator function is a bit hard to read: $\{ (u,v): 0\le u \le 1, u \le v \le u+1 \}$)

I want to determine $C$ so this function can be considered a PDF. In other words, I need to show that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy=1$$

---

Here is my **first problem**:

I am having difficulties converting the subscript from the indicator function into an integral. My attempt:

$$C\int_0^1 \int_u^{u+1}1  \space dvdu=C\int_0^1  (v)\lvert_{u}^{u+1}du=C\int_0^11du=C$$

So in order for this to be normalized and satisfy the property, $C=1$. Is this correct or am I misreading the bounds from the indicator function?

---

Here is my **second problem**:

I want to determine the marginal PDF's $f_X$ and $f_Y$ from the joint PDF. I know this can be achieved by integrating over the "other" variable. For $f_Y$ the formula is:

$$\begin{align}%
\\
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dx, \hspace{10pt} \textrm{ for all }y.
\end{align}$$

Similar problem to the first problem. My bounds are not independent from each other so I am not sure how to write the integral. How do I set up my bounds here? My attempt:

$$f_Y=\int_0^21dx=2 \\ \implies f_Y= \begin{cases}2 \hspace{10pt} \text{for} \hspace{10pt} 0 \le y\le2 \\ 0 \hspace{10pt} \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is it $(x, y)$ and $(u, v)$ the same?

Comment: @WillM. I am not sure. This is the way the question is worded. I am guessing $u,v$ are sort of dummy variables?

Comment: Aha, I see. You probably know that $1_A(x, y)$ means 1 for $(x, y) \in A$ and zero otherwise. They are defining $A$ as a set of pairs $(u, v),$ hence my confusion. You have to think of $(u, v)$ to be $(x, y).$

Comment: @WillM. So if they are just the "same", could I write:

$$f_X=\int_0^1 dy =1$$

and 

$$f_Y=\int_{x}^{x+1} dx=?$$

for the marginal PDF's?

Comment: The marginal probabilities are $f_X(x) = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} dy f_{X, Y}(x, y)$ and similarly for $f_Y(y).$ If you are integrating the function $\mathbf{1}_{0 \leq x \leq 1, x \leq y \leq x + 1}$ for a fixed $x$ over all of $y,$ then you are integrating the constant function $1$ over the interval $[x, x + 1]$  whenever $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and the constant function $0$ for all other values of $x.$

Comment: In the reverse, when you integrate over $x$ for a fixed value of $y,$ then you have the constraints $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x \leq y \leq x +1$ which can be rewritten as $0 \leq y \leq 2$ and $\max(0, y - 1) \leq x \leq \min(1, y).$ And you can set up the appropriate interval based upon this. And if you cannot, do a drawing like the answer below suggests. I am analytical and can work with equations, but some people prefer to see things (just be cautios that a visualisation method is bounded to fail every time dimension is greater than 2 while handling equations never fails).

Comment: @WillM. Thanks you for your help. I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indicator is clear...what is wrong is that you have $f(u,v)$ and not $f(x,y)$

The support is a parallelogram (do a drawing to realize that) with area $1$ thus your density is uniform over this parallelogram and $C=1$, the reciprocal of the support area. No integrals are needed.

[image]

To get the two marginals you have to integrate

- $f_U(u)=\int_u^{u+1}dv=1$

That is $U\sim U(0;1)$

For $V$ you have to observe that,

- when $v \in(0;1)$ you have

$$f_V(v)=\int_0^v du=v$$

- when $v \in[1;2)$ you have

$$f_V(v)=\int_{v-1}^1 du=2-v$$

concluding, $f_V$ is a triangular density

This is a compact way to write it

$$f_V(v)=[1-|1-v|]\mathbb{1}_{(0;2)}(v)$$

Comment: Thanks! I am still digesting your answer but I have a question about the first part. I am pretty new to this indicator function notation so it confuses me a lot. If I were to put this function: $$f(x,y):= C \cdot \unicode[STIXGeneral]{x1D7D9}_{\{ (u,v): 0\le u \le 1, u \le v \le u+1 \}}(x,y)$$

in words, would it be: $f(x,y)$ is equal to $C$ when  $0 \le x \le 1$ and $x \le y \le x+1$ otherwise $f(x,y)$ is zero?

Comment: @Nullspace yes, exatly. The support is the parallelogram between the two lines $u$ and $u+1$ or $x$ and $x+1$, as you prefer

Comment: @Nullspace:  I added a drawing of the joint support

Comment: I tried to figure out the second part but I am having difficulties. This is what I got so far:
The marginal PDF $f_X$ can be obtained by:

$$f_X= \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy=\int_0^1 dy =1$$

The marginal PDF $f_Y$ can be obtained by:

$$f_Y=\int_{x}^{x+1} dx=1$$

This doesn't seem right and is also different than what you have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nullspace: You cannot integrate in $\int_0^1$ because the support is not a rectangle, it's a parallelogram. To understand the correct integral bounds you have to be familiar with  double integration. First take a look at the drawing I did then try to understand the correct integral bounds I showed

Comment: Ah I see now! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have a small follow up question that I didn't want to make a new question for. Is there a way to show if $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are independet. I know that for them to be independent it needs to hold: $$f(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(x) \forall x,y$$

But is there some clever way to show if this holds?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to show if $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are independent?

They are not independent. This follows immediately without any calculation because a "Necessary Condition" for independence is that the joint support is a rectangle. Here it is a parallelogram thus the two marginals cannot be independent.

---

To get a proof, first observe that the condition

$$f_{UV}(u,v)=f_U(u)\cdot f_V(v)$$

is equivalent to

$$f_{U}(u)=f_{U|V}(u|v)$$

and in your case you have, as a counterexample:

$$\mathbb{P}[U<0.5]=0.5$$

but

$$\mathbb{P}[U<0.5|V>1.5]=0$$

this evidently prove that $U,V$ are not independent because the probability of $U$ changes w.r.t. the occurrence of $V$

Comment: Awesome! That makes so much sense. The example you provided really helped me understand. Thanks again for your help today and yesterday!